# cannot POST successful ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 files in my repository and I want to pass a js variable in index.php to a php script validate.php. The structure of my repository:

- index/index. php
- pdf/validate.php

The code in index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
The content of the document......
<script type="text/javascript">

var name = "virginia"
//console.log(name)

$.ajax({
    url: "../pdf/validate.php", 
    method: "post", 
    data: name, 
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(name)
        console.log("pass js variable to php: success")
    }

});  

// open localhost/index.php
// open F12 developer console, you will find 'virginia' was passed to validate.php, because it console-prints "pass js variable to php: success". 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The ajax request was successful to validate.php. But, going over to validate.php,  I have:

```
<?php 
$var1 = $_POST['name']; 
echo($var1); 
?>
```

If I open validate.php in localhost, i get the error message: Notice: Undefined index: name.

Why?

Comment: Because you're posting a plain string, pass an object in `data` property.

Answer (score 2):

> The ajax request was successful to validate.php

Not that successful.

You haven't formatted the data correctly for PHP to parse it.

You should pass an object with a `name` property to data.

```
data: { name },
```

You could tell that it is currently failing if you had examined `res` instead of `name` with your `console.log`.

---

> If I open validate.php in localhost, i get the error message: Notice: Undefined index: name.

By typing the URL in the browser, you are making a **new** GET request that is completely unrelated to the POST request you made with JavaScript previously.

The POST data from the first request doesn't exist in the second request.

---

If you want data to persist between requests then you need to store it somewhere (such as a session or a database) and add logic to distinguish between setting and retrieving the data (keying off the request being POST or GET for example).